# php array keys which contain a word

Tags: php, arrays

I have a large SQL query which returns aggregate data.

My returned array is something like this:

```
array(37) { // I get 37 arrays returned 
    [0] => array(10) {
        ["groupId"] => string(1) "3"  // the first param is just an id  
        ["sessionCount84"] => string(1) "0"   
        ["sessionCount1"] => string(1) "1" 
    } ...
```

Each sub-array will contains multiple keys with the word 'sessionCount' and a number following that and there could be many of them.

Is there a way to get all the values for keys which contain the words 'sessionCount[someNumber]" ?

I tried the array_keys function in php, but that requires an exact word match, meaning I would need to know the number following 'sessionCount' in the key, so I'd need to get all the keys that contain that word first somehow.

Comment: loop over the array ^^

Comment: @Steve thanks a bunch, I wasn't able to find that myself for some reason

Comment: This returned data suggests poor table design. Why isn't `sessionCount` a dependent table instead of dozens of columns?

Comment: sessionCount is not its own table, the sessionCount is a result of an aggregate function on other existing tables that span across multiple schemas conditionally and are grouped by conditional primary keys.  Basically, I have a large amount of schemas and a large amount of tables in each schema and this result is a 'report' being run across many of them at once, joining many tables together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$tmp = array();
foreach ($array as $sub)
    foreach ($sub as $k => $v)
        if (substr($k, 0, 12) == 'sessionCount')
            $tmp[$k] = $v;
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like this will help.

```
$myArray = array(37) { [0]=>  // I get 37 arrays returned  
    array(10) { ["groupId"]=> string(1) "3"  // the first param is just an id  
    ["sessionCount84"]=> string(1) "0"   
    ["sessionCount1"]=> string(1) "1" } ...

$sessions = array();
array_map(function($session) use (&$sessions) {
    foreach ($session as $key => $value) {
        if ($key starts with "sessionCount") // I'm going to leave that up to you
            $sessions[$key] = $value;
    }
}, $myArray);
```

Comment: This was a little more procession than I needed, but thank you anyway

Answer (score 0):

without changing the array you can only do this by brute force.. aka. try "sessionCount[0-999]"..

a different approach would be to use strcmp() on the array keys like so:

```
foreach($array as $key => $value) 
    if(!strcmp($key,"sessionCount")) 
        dosomething($key,$value);
```

or loop through your array once and restructure it to something like this:

```
array() {
  ["sessionCount"] => array() {
      [84] => "",
      [1] => "",
  }
}
```

..after that finding all the keys you require should be a walk in the park. ;)

Comment: I agree the structure should be better, perhaps in the SQL.. but being able to restructure your array is also the answer to the original problem.

Comment: I wish I could structure it better, but my experience with SQL is not that great, I assume that the above structure would require some sub-querying?

Comment: it would require you to look at the foreach() above the structuring. ;)